# What is an efficient way to query against an entity-attribute-value model

Tags: mysql, entity-attribute-value

I'm working with a database set up like this:

```
  entity field       value
   1      start_date  June 1, 2010
   1      end_date    August 30, 2010
   1      artist      some name
```

And I want to query all the entities with artist name "some name" that have started but not ended.

I came up with something like this:

```
SELECT start.entity
FROM field_values AS `start`
  INNER JOIN field_values AS `end`
  INNER JOIN field_values AS `artist`
WHERE 
  (start.field = 'start_date' AND end.field = 'end_date' AND artist.field='artist')  AND 
  (STR_TO_DATE(start.value, '%M %d, %Y') < NOW() AND 
   STR_TO_DATE(end.value, '%M %d, %Y') > NOW())  AND 
  artist.value="some artist";
```

But this doesn't strike me as being incredibly efficient. Is there a better approach to this?

Comment: The most efficient solution is to convert those attributes into columns and do away with the EAV. :)

Comment: @Thomas How I wish I could do that

Comment: To expand on what Thomas is saying: This EAV idea isn't worthless, but you don't want to use it for attributes that are important to defining the entities. You know an attribute is definitely 'too essential for EAV' when you want to use it in JOINs, ORDER BYs, or WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity you can put the join clause items in the join clause, but in terms of query optimisation that is pretty much the way to do it.

You could consider rewriting the query to something like this though:

```
SELECT start.entity
FROM entity
  JOIN field_values AS start
    ON entity.id = start.entity AND start.field = 'start_date'
  INNER JOIN field_values AS end
    ON entity.id = end.entity AND end.field = 'end_date'
  INNER JOIN field_values AS artist
    ON entity.id = artist.entity AND artist.field = 'artist'
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(start.value, '%M %d, %Y') < NOW()
  AND STR_TO_DATE(end.value, '%M %d, %Y') > NOW()
  AND artist.value="some artist"
;
```

You could also normalize the field to save a little space (assuming that field is not an enum)

Comment: It's mainly convention, the `WHERE` part is actually to filter the results. The `ON` is for the actual join conditions which would remain the same between queries.

Comment: wouldn't it be faster if conditions were evaluated during joining rather after?

Comment: No, it's only a different syntax. The database should evaluate it identically. Perhaps you are confusing `WHERE` with `HAVING`?

Answer (score 1):

While EAV has it's place, you already have 3 somewhat guaranteed attribute names (as you are searching for it I assume a lot of entities share those attributes). Smells like a non-candidate for EAV, or a possible combination of attributes which may go in their seperate table `artistdates (id,artist,start,end)`, which could possibly link in the EAV table as `E=<whatever>,A=artistdate_id,V=<artistdate_id>` if you like.

The power of EAV is for those situations in which the actual attributes present are not consistent, and which are usually queried by solely entity-id, or the existence of an attribute (possibly in combination with a value). As soon as you're looking for combinations of attributes performance *will* suffer and the question is whether those should live separately in the EAV structure or they should be split out into a 'traditional' row based table.

Comment: I know this can be done without EAV, unfortunately, I'm not at liberty to change the database.

Comment: Then a performance hit is what you shall take, unfortunately. Nothing wrong with your actual query.